# How to shorten If SVO+prep. A, then SVO+prep. B.?

Tags: abbreviations

How to shorten the following sentence?

> If the teacher brings a gift for Adam, then the teacher brings a gift for Barbara.

This sentence does not make much sense. My question is if there is a formula (like ·so does it·) to shorten "If SVO+prep. A, then SVO+prep. B."

Comment: A gift for Adam from the teacher means Barbara gets one too.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shorten this sentence this way:

> If the teacher gives Adam a gift, then (he/she) does likewise for Barbara.

*One* replaces *gift*.

What I noticed in your sentence:

- The verb must be conjugated to the 3rd person singular in this context.
- *Bring* and *give* don't have necessarily the same meaning.
- In this context, we use the preposition *to* (ex: *give it to me*), but I use *for* in my sentence for another reason. Of course, we can say *give me*.
- We can replace information with other words like pronouns, nominal groups etc.